# Making groups (combinations) of objects using their min/max values

Tags: grouping, combinations, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

First of all, this is my first question, you can tell me how to improve it and what tags to use.

What I am trying to do is I have a bunch of objects that have minimal and maximal values by those values you can deduce if two objects have some sort of overlapping value and thus they can be put together in a group

This question might need dynamic programming to solve.

### example objects:

```
1 ( min: 0, max: 2 )
2 ( min: 1, max: 3 )
3 ( min: 2, max: 4 )
4 ( min: 3, max: 5 )
```

- object 1 can be grouped with objects 2, 3
- object 2 can be grouped with objects 1, 3, 4
- object 3 can be grouped with objects 1, 2, 4
- object 4 can be grouped with objects 2, 3

as you can see there are multiple ways to group those elements

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]

[1]
[2, 3]
[4]

[1]
[2, 3, 4]

[1, 2, 3]
[4]
```

now there should be some sort of rule to deduce which of the solutions is the best solution

- for example least amount of groups

  [1, 2]
  [3, 4]

  or

  [1]
  [2, 3, 4]

  or

  [1, 2, 3]
  [4]
- or most objects in one group

  [1]
  [2, 3, 4]

  or

  [1, 2, 3]
  [4]
- or any other rule that uses another attribute of said objects to compare the solutions

### what I have now:

```
$objects = [...objects...];

$numberOfObjects = count($objects);
$groups    = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfObjects; $i++) {
    $MinA           = $objects[$i]['min'];
    $MaxA           = $objects[$i]['max'];
    $groups[$i]    = [$i];
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $numberOfObjects; $j++) {
        $MinB = $objects[$j]['min'];
        $MaxB = $objects[$j]['max'];
        if (($MinA >= $MinB && $MinA <= $MaxB) || ($MaxA >= $MinB && $MaxA <= $MaxB) || ($MinB >= $MinA && $MinB <= $MaxA)) {
            array_push($groups[$i], $j);
        }
    }
}
```

this basically creates an array with indexes of objects that can be grouped together

from this point, I don't know how to proceed, how to generate all the solution and then check each of them how good it is, and the pick the best one

or maybe there is even better solution that doesn't use any of this?

PHP solutions are preferred, although this problem is not PHP-specific

Comment: are the results that you show like `[1,2]` in the second block from your algorithm? It looks like you're missing `[2]` and `[3]`

Comment: I wrote them out by hand as an example, no need to write solo objects, because grouping any solo objects is always better in all cases, than to keep them separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was first looking at your algorithm, I was impressed by how efficient it is :)
Here it is rewritten in javascript, because I moved away from perl a good while ago:

```
function setsOf(objects){
  numberOfObjects = objects.length
  groups    = []
  let i
  for (i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
      MinA           = objects[i]['min']
      MaxA           = objects[i]['max']
      groups[i]    = [i]
      for (j = i + 1; j < numberOfObjects; j++) {
          MinB = objects[j]['min']
          MaxB = objects[j]['max']
          if ((MinA >= MinB && MinA <= MaxB) || (MaxA >= MinB && MaxA <= MaxB) || 
            (MinB >= MinA && MinB <= MaxA)) {
              groups[i].push(j)
          }
      }
  }
  return groups
}
```

if you happen to also think well in javascript, you might find this form more direct (it is identical, however):

```
function setsOf(objects){
  let groups = []
  objects.forEach((left,i) => {
    groups[i]=[i]
    Array.from(objects).splice(i+1).forEach((right, j) => {
      if ((left.min >= right.min && left.min <= right.max) || 
          (left.max >=right.max && left.max <= right.max) || 
          (right.min >= left.min && right.min <= left.max))
        groups[i].push(j+i+1)
    })
  })
  return groups
}
```

so if we run it, we get:

```
a = setsOf([{min:0, max:2}, {min:1, max:3}, {min:2, max:4}, {min:3, max: 5}])
[Array(3), Array(3), Array(2), Array(1)]0: Array(3)1: Array(3)2: Array(2)3: Array(1)length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
JSON.stringify(a)
"[[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]"
```

and it does impressively catch the compound groups :) a weakness is that it is capturing groups containing more objects than necessary, without capturing all available objects. You seem to have a very custom selection criteria. To me, it seems like the groups should either be every last intersecting subset, or only subsets where each element in the group provides unique coverage: `[0,1], [0,2], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [0,1,3]`

the algorithm for that is perhaps more involved. this was my approach, and it is nowhere near as terse and elegant as yours, but it works:

```
function intersectingGroups (mmvs) {
  const min = []
  const max = []
  const muxo = [...mmvs]

  mmvs.forEach(byMin => {
    mmvs.forEach(byMax => { 
      if (byMin.min === byMax.min && byMin.max === byMax.max) {
        console.log('rejecting identity', byMin, byMax)
        return // identity
      }
      if (byMax.min > byMin.max) {
        console.log('rejecting non-overlapping objects', byMin, byMax)
        return // non-overlapping objects
      }
      if ((byMax.max <= byMin.max) || (byMin.min >= byMax.min)) {
        console.log('rejecting non-expansive coverage or inversed order', 
          byMin, byMax)
        return // non-expansive coverage or inversed order
      }
      const entity = {min: byMin.min, max: byMax.max, 
        compositeOf: [byMin, byMax]}
      if(muxo.some(mv => mv.min === entity.min && mv.max === entity.max))
        return // enforcing Set
      muxo.push(entity)
      console.log('adding', byMin, byMax, muxo)
    })
  })

  if(muxo.length === mmvs.length) {
    return muxo.filter(m => 'compositeOf' in m)
    // solution
  } else {
    return intersectingGroups(muxo)
  } 
}
```

#### now there should be some sort of rule to deduce which of the solutions is the best solution

Yeah, so, usually for puzzles or for a specification you are fulfilling, that would be given as part of the problem. As it is, you want a general method that is adaptable. It's probably best to make an object that can be configured with the results and accepts rules, then load the rules you are interested in, and the results from the search, and see what rules match where. For example, using your algorithm and sample criteria:

#### least amount of groups

start with code like:

```
let reviewerFactory = {
  getReviewer (specification) { // generate a reviewer
    return { 
      matches: [], // place to load sets to
      criteria: specification,
      review (objects) { // review the sets already loaded
        let group
        let results = {}
        this.matches.forEach(mset => {
          group = [] // gather each object from the initial set for each match in the result set
          mset.forEach(m => {
            group.push(objects[m])
          })
          results[mset] = this.criteria.scoring(group) // score the match relative to the specification
        })
        return this.criteria.evaluation(results) // pick the best score
       }
    }
  },
  specifications: {}
}
```

now you can add specifications like this one for least amount of groups:

```
reviewerFactory.specifications['LEAST GROUPS'] =  {
  scoring: function (set) { return set.length },
  evaluation: function (res) { return Object.keys(res).sort((a,b) => res[a] - res[b])[0] }
}
```

then you can use that in the evaluation of a set:

```
mySet = [{min:0, max:2}, {min:1, max:3}, {min:2, max:4}, {min:3, max: 5}]
rf = reviewerFactory.getReviewer(reviewerFactory.specifications['LEAST GROUPS'])
Object {matches: Array(0), criteria: Object, review: function}
rf.matches = setsOf(mySet)
[Array(3), Array(3), Array(2), Array(1)]
rf.review(mySet)
"3"
```

or, most objects:

```
reviewerFactory.specifications['MOST GROUPS'] =  {
  scoring: function (set) { return set.length },
  evaluation: function (res) { return Object.keys(res).sort((a,b) => res[a] - res[b]).reverse()[0] }
}

mySet = [{min:0, max:2}, {min:1, max:3}, {min:2, max:4}, {min:3, max: 5}]
reviewer = reviewerFactory.getReviewer(reviewerFactory.specifications['MOST GROUPS'])
reviewer.matches = setsOf(mySet)
reviewer.review(mySet)
"1,2,3"
```

Of course this is arbitrary, but so are the criteria, by definition in the OP. Likewise, you would have to change the algorithms here to work with my `intersectingGroups` function because it doesn't return indices. But this is what you are looking for I believe.

Comment: thank you, I will try my best to implement this and tell you the results, but I am kinda busy at the moment, so apologies

Comment: it appears I am not as good at javascript as I thought, could you please add comments in your code what each block does?

Comment: hi, Im sorry, I forgot to update the factory after debugging the specifications! I've updated the code .. it should work now